# Receiving empty data from Kafka - Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Why am I getting empty data messages when I read a topic from kafka?
Is it a problem with the Decoder?

*There is no error or exception.

Code:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Queue Status")

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(1))
ssc.checkpoint("/tmp/")

val kafkaConfig = Map("zookeeper.connect" -> "ip.internal:2181",
  "group.id" -> "queue-status")
val kafkaTopics = Map("queue_status" -> 1)

val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream[String, QueueStatusMessage, StringDecoder, QueueStatusMessageKafkaDeserializer](
  ssc,
  kafkaConfig,
  kafkaTopics,
  StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

kafkaStream.window(Minutes(1),Seconds(10)).print()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination() 
}
```

The Kafka decoder:

```
class QueueStatusMessageKafkaDeserializer(props: VerifiableProperties = null) extends Decoder[QueueStatusMessage] {
  override def fromBytes(bytes: Array[Byte]): QueueStatusMessage = QueueStatusMessage.parseFrom(bytes)
}
```

The (empty) result:

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1440010266000 ms
-------------------------------------------
(null,QueueStatusMessage(,,0,None,None))
(null,QueueStatusMessage(,,0,None,None))
(null,QueueStatusMessage(,,0,None,None))
(null,QueueStatusMessage(,,0,None,None))
```

---

**Solution:**

Just strictly specified the types in the Kafka topic Map:

```
val kafkaTopics = Map[String, Int]("queue_status" -> 1)
```

Still don't know the reason for the problem, but the code is working fine now.

Comment: When you get > 15 reputation you should anwer your own question:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question